# Magento 1.9 registration optional address

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.9, registration

is it possible to make the address only in the registration form optional?

I would like to give the user the option to click on a checkbox like "Add address" and then the input fields for the address will appear.

But it's still necessary that the address field is required when the user has clicked on "Add address". If this checkbox isn't checked, those fields will not be visible or aren't required.

Any idead if this is possible? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is for sure possible, although there is no built-in config option for this.

You will have to write js code to toggle validation with your checkbox (remove/add validation classes from input fields for example)

this is not tested but should give you a hint how it works

```js
$('.toggle-addressform').click(function() {
 $$('[name="create_address"]')[0].value = ($$('[name="create_address"]')[0].value)? 0:1;

 $('telephone').toggleClassName('required-entry');
 $('street_1').toggleClassName('required-entry');
 $('city').toggleClassName('required-entry');
 $('region_id').toggleClassName('validate-select');
 $('region').toggleClassName('required-entry');
 $('zip').toggleClassName('validate-zip-international');
 $('zip').toggleClassName('required-entry');
 $('country').toggleClassName('required-entry');
});
```

```html
<input class="toggle-addressform" type="checkbox" name="toggle-addressform">
```